# switching windows fails

Tags: watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

What am I doing wrong.  Script times out when can not find newly open window.

```
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill': Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rbuf_fill'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1319:in `block in transport_request'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `catch'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `transport_request'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1286:in `block in request'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/sele
nium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:82:in `response_for'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/sele
nium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:38:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/sele
nium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/sele
nium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/sele
nium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:576:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/sele
nium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:207:in `getWindowHandles'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/sele
nium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:185:in `window_handles'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-we
bdriver/window.rb:119:in `locate'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-we
bdriver/window.rb:106:in `handle'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-we
bdriver/window.rb:99:in `use'
        from tst.rb:38:in `rescue in <main>'
        from tst.rb:31:in `<main>'
```

--

```
begin
Timeout::timeout(10) do
   b.frame(:id, "ifContentBody").link(:text, "Filter").click
  puts b.check_for_http_error()
end
  rescue Exception => e
  puts "try get popup"
  b.window(:url, 'https://www.XXXXX.com/XXXX/aspx/InvestmentDetailOptions.aspx?IDAssetType=').use do
 puts b.check_for_http_error()
 b.button(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_btnSubmit2").click
 end
```

end

Please advise.  I am using watir-webdriver with chrome.  I have tried everything 
watirspec look like it would work but I could not figure it out.

Thanks

M

Comment: Is this not the same as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882974/cant-access-popup-with-ruby-watir-webdriver)?

Comment: Same issue but, I am trying to switch windows instead of attaching to browser. Sorry just getting desperate to get his issue resolved.

Comment: Is the page you are trying to work with public? Or can you create a sample HTML that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Page is private requires login authorization I click a link, `<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_ctrlPageHeader1_aFilter" class="RightTextHeading" onclick="javascript:openMdlWindow('InvestmentDetailOptions.aspx?IDAssetType=','620','600');if(window.document.RetValue == '2'){window.parent.LoadinIframe('InvestmentDetail.aspx?FromMenu=N&amp;IDAssetType=','Investment Details &gt; Full View','false');}" style="text-decoration:none;">Filter</a>`  after link is clicked it opens a popup containing a form that needs to be filled in and then submit button clicked to continue.